# Const-ness issues: how to traverse a linked list of Objects in D?

Tags: class, object, linked-list, d

If I have a class like:

```
class Node
{
    string id;
    const Node next;
}
```

How do I find, say, the `id` of the last `Node` in the linked list?

```
string lastID(const Node node)
{
    ???
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your problem is that you need to loop but can't reset your variable, because it's const? If you want to have an object which refers to a const object but is re-assignable itself (i.e. it's tail-const), then use `std.typecons.Rebindable`. In this case, that gives you:

```
string lastID(const Node node)
{
    import std.typecons;
    Rebindable!(const Node) curr = node;

    while(curr.next)
        curr = curr.next;

    return curr.id;
}
```

I must say that I find it a bit odd though that you don't just ask about how to have a reference to a const object where the reference isn't const itself, since that's all I can see that you're really asking here, given how straightforward the loop itself is. As it stands, your question is a bit too much along the lines of asking someone to write your code for you rather than asking a question.

Comment: Yes, that was the exact problem -- I couldn't loop because it was const, and I couldn't break `const` because that would've been undefined behavior. Seems like `Rebindable` is the answer, I completely forgot about that struct; thanks.

Comment: @Mehrdad, Casting away const is not undefind.

Comment: It's casting away `const` and then mutating which is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go fancy and use recursion:

```
string lastID(const Node node)
{
    if(node.next)
        return lastID(node.next);
    return node.id;
}
```

Do take in mind that it might cause a stack overflow if the list is very long(as far as I know D does not support tail call recursion optimization)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly why I didn't use recursion, it's not practical without a guarantee of tail recursion.

Comment: dmd currently optimizes tail recursion but not tail calls. Tail 
recursion == function calls itself as the last expression. Tail call == function issues a call to another function as the last expression. Without tail call optimization, mutual recursion will consume stack as you noted.
http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D&artnum=118506